# Do not treat specific warning as error in MSVC

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I want to compile my project with /W3 /WX - most warnings treated as errors. However one particular warning is hard to fix, so I want compiler to continue signaling it as warning for now.

I don't want to disable it completely, in that case team members won't see that their code requires a fix, so this warning will never be fixed.

How can I disable /WX for particular warning ID?

Comment: AFAIK, you can't. We also tried this, where we wanted all warnings as errors, but some just as warnings. The only workaround is to treat them all as warnings, and add EVERY warning (besides the one) as an error, but obviously this is not ideal

Comment: Yeah, this does not sound optimal, will require a lot of flags to be added. Also hard to maintain between compiler versions